# How to get the Device UUID on the Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, uuid

Calling `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` returns nil and "`unable to determine UUID for host. Error: 35`" message in the console. Where is the UUID stored on the simulator?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using a Hackintosh? Please check http://osx86scene.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2027&start=15.

<del>There is no UDID for the simulator.</del>

<del>The UDID is computed (not stored, it's computed) based on the serial number and other globally unique addresses in the background daemon `lockdownd` on the iPhoneOS. Since the serial number, etc. do not exist on the simulator, the UDID cannot be computed, and thus `nil` is returned.</del>

Comment: @castor: Which SDK you're using?

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!!! IT WORKS!!!! I'm using Hackintosh and after adding some strings to NetworkPreferences.plist, method uniqueIdentifier return not nil value.